# How does ngCloak work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngcloak

```
<html ng-app>
  <body>
    <p ng-cloak>{{foo}}</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The way I understand it:

1. The HTML page is rendered.
2. DOMContentLoaded is emitted, and Angular starts its bootstrap process.
3. During the compile phase, when it sees the `ng-cloak` directive, it applies `display: none !important`.
4. During/after the link phase and before the re-rendering, it removes that `display: none !important` rule from things with the `ng-cloak` directive.

So I understand why things wouldn't be shown from the time the compile phase starts to the end of the link phase. But I don't understand why things wouldn't be shown from the time the HTML is loaded to the start of the compile phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all explained in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak):

> [...] When this css rule is loaded by the browser, all html elements (including their children) that are tagged with the ngCloak directive are hidden. When Angular encounters this directive during the compilation of the template it deletes the ngCloak element attribute, making the compiled element visible.

Comment: Ohh ok. I forgot that attribute selectors were a thing and didn't understand what they were saying there, but it all makes sense now. I had a brain fart and overcomplicated it.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the explanation in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak). I've worked on websites that use async calls to retrieve data and I've used ng-cloak to avoid showing variables that might not have a value yet until the end of the compile process. My use case is when the DOMContent might have finished loading way before the compile process ends but my Angular data is not ready yet. Hope this gives you an idea of a use case but that's not the only one.